# Track move operations on nodes over the entire repo

Tags: java, osgi, aem-6

Track the node move operations over the whole repo.
Node can be of anytype.
Node Move operation may happen through the following options:
1. Drag drop through crxde
2. Move operations from damadmin or siteadmin

Could anyone please guide on what events the move operation can be tracked.

Created a event listener to catch the node movement event.
Event type used are NODE_ADDED, NODE_MOVED, NODE_REMOVED.
Created a config mentioning the paths which the eventListner should read, to catch the move Event of nodes (e.g. /content , /content/dam, /apps/myproject, etc/myproject)
But unable to catch the event through the the above Events operations.
When i move the node(anytype), the onEvent method is not called.

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = EventListener.class,
        configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public final class MoveEventListener implements EventListener {

    /* Config property to read paths */
    private static final String REPO_PATH = "content.rootpath";
    private static final String LAST_MODIFIED_BY = "cq:lastModifiedBy";

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
    private Session session;
    private ObservationManager observationManager;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MoveEventListener.class);

    private String[] repoPaths;

    /**
     * Activate method.
     *
     * @param context **ComponentContext**
     */
    @Activate
    protected void activate(final ComponentContext context) {
        try {
            log.debug("Inside Activate Move Listener");
            resourceResolver = ResourceResolverUtils.getResourceResolver(resolverFactory,
                    GlobalConstants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MPASPRODUCTS_DISPATCHER_FLUSH);
            session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
            observationManager = session != null
                    ? (session.getWorkspace() != null ? session.getWorkspace().getObservationManager() : null)
                    : null;
            repoPaths = (String[]) context.getProperties().get(REPO_PATH);

            final String[] types = {"nt:unstructured", "sling:Folder", "sling:OrderedFolder", "nt:folder", "dam:Asset",
                    "cq:Page", "cq:PageContent"};
            /* final String[] types = {DamConstants.NT_DAM_ASSETCONTENT, StringConstants.NT_UNSTRUCTURED,
                    NameConstants.NT_PAGE, GlobalConstants.CQ_PAGECONTENT}; */

            if (repoPaths != null) {
                for (String path : repoPaths) {
                    log.debug("Paths: " + path);
                    if (observationManager != null) {
                        observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.NODE_ADDED | Event.NODE_MOVED | Event.NODE_REMOVED,
                                path, true, null, types, false);
                        log.debug("Observing movement of nodes under {}", Arrays.asList(types), path);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occured in {} activation ", getClass(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deactivate method.
     */
    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() {
        if (resourceResolver != null) {
            resourceResolver.close();
        }
        log.info(this + " component - deactiviated");
    }

    /**
     * Event handling class.
     *
     * @param events
     */
    @Override
    public void onEvent(final EventIterator events) {
        log.debug("Inside On event");
        while (events.hasNext()) {
            Event event = events.nextEvent();
            if (event.getType() == Event.NODE_ADDED || event.getType() == Event.NODE_MOVED || event.getType() == Event.NODE_REMOVED) {
                log.debug("Event occured in {}", event.getType());
                try {
                    String path = event.getPath();
                    Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(path);
                    if (resource != null) {
                        ValueMap value = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
                        if (value != null) {
                            String lastModifiedBy = value.get(LAST_MODIFIED_BY, String.class);
                            log.debug(path + " " + "Node moved" + " last modified by: "
                                    + lastModifiedBy);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error found while processing event: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you didn't register to the appropriate events.

To my knowledge, It is not certain which kind of events will happen when you play with the nodes. You can use http://localhost:4502/system/console/events to see which events are happening in the system and register to the ones you are interested in.

When I move /content/dam/asset.jpg to /content/dam/test/asset.jpg I see an event which you can use. Event details are as below:

```
Event Topic: org/apache/sling/event/notification/job/START
event.job.topic: com/adobe/cq/workflow/payload/move/job
payload.move.src.path: /content/dam/asset.jpg
payload.move.dest.path: /content/dam/test/asset.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already created a service user and provided the required permissions. Along with the new system user, you have to map the user in the Sling Mapper Service. If the user is not mapped in the Sling Mapper Service, you will not be able to get the system user details and will not be able to track the events. If this is not done, you should be able to see errors in your log file when refreshing/restarting the bundle.

> Step by Step procedure for the requirement:
>
> 1. Create a system User
> 2. Provide the required permissions
> 3. Map the user in Sling Mapping Service
> 4. Install the Event Listener (Deploy the code)
> 5. Test the event changes

For more details on simple listener, you can refer to https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem64_event_listener.html

You can refer to the sample below for listening the node addition or deletion

> https://github.com/sudheerdvn/aem-flash/blob/develop/core/src/main/java/com/flash/aem/core/listeners/SimpleEventListener.java

If you refer to Line 56: i have provided the path as "/content", So all the events under **"/content"** will be listened in this listener, you can limit the listener by changing this path to limited set of folders.

Comment: Yes, all the above steps are already in place. Able to track the move event on pages by capturing the Event.PROPERTY_CHANGED | Event.NODE_MOVED on cq:Page & cq:PageContent.
However not able to track move event on the dam assets.

Comment: Have edited my answer and provided a sample event listener which listens to any event under /content, can be page or a dam asset